# How to create more then one master pages with different layouts in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new in ASP.Net and doing my final year project in asp.net without using any framework or MVC. In my web application there are four modules like student, supervisor etc. Each module has a different dashboard. What i did is that i made a master page for students and displayed main menu according to their requirement. I also created another master page for supervisor module with different main menu as well. Now when i try to create a dashboard for supervisor and when i include master page it says child master page must have a reference of parent master page so what i did is i searched for this error on google and create master page with reference of parent master page. Now when i try to create dashboard for supervisor and adds master page what happens is that the parent master page is added to supervisor dashboard with same menus as student but I do not want that I want to have a different menus for supervisor and i store them in master page. So what should i do now how can i create a separate file for supervisor and include that in dashboard in case if master page do not work?

Comment: So if you're not using MVC, and you've mentioned "Master Pages", may we assume you're using Web Forms?

Comment: yes i am using web forms

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [Nested Master Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx). In your case, you probably want something like...

**Base.Master**

This should include things that are global/required by everything (like script/css files)

**Student.Master** *extends* **Base.Master** *(Nested Master Page)*

This should include things that are specific to a student, like the student's menu

**Supervisor.Master** *extends* **Base.Master** *(Nested Master Page)*

This should include things that are specific to a supervisor, like the supervisor's menu

Whenever you create a new Student or Supervisor, you create a new Page from the associated master page.

i.e. **SupervisorDashboard.aspx** *extends* **Supervisor.Master**

*Note: This is all pseudo-code. I'm not going to write your final year project for you...just give you a gentle nudge in the right direction :)*